# Presenting UIAlertController on subview causing window hierarchy warning in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

This code has been working perfectly since iOS 4. I'm doing a preferences UITableViewController that's underneath the main view controller. When the prefs button is pressed, the main view slides to the left, showing the prefs table view. Very simple.

One of the preferences items brought up a UIActionSheet. The problem is that in iOS 8, UIActionSheet is deprecated. Ok, so the easy thing to do would be to move to UIAlertController. Well, the problem is that when I click on the row that's supposed to bring up the UIAlertController, I get this:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7cab8bf0> on <PrefsTableController: 0x7be5c5b0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

This does not happen in iOS 6 or iOS 7.

The code to place the prefs vc is:

```
[self.window insertSubview:prefsTableController.view belowSubview:viewController.view];
```

Nothing to it, and it works great. The problem is that I don't understand why the view is now considered to be detached in iOS 8 when I clearly placed it in a view hierarchy.

The code that presents the UIAlertContoller is:

```
[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So, I'm at a total loss here. If I explicitly place view B under view A, why am I being told that view B is not in the view hierarchy?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `self` in `[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: The bottom preferences view controller.

Comment: I used the Xcode 6 3D window hierarchy display view and it's actually in the right place.

Comment: To be honest, it's very weird to insert a subview that way. @ryanipete's answer looks more in the right direction. Also, I assume `view` is a view controller? It's a bit confusing.

Comment: I suggest to go with UIAlertView.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your prefsTableController (not just its view) to the hierarchy.

Edit: One option is to you set your UITableViewController as the child of a custom container view controller and then, when you're ready to show preferences, add prefsViewController as another child of the same container (details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW1)).